# Using Javascript async & await with google.script.url.getLocation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, async-await, refactoring

I am trying to refactor some ugly code in a Google Apps Script web application so that it uses `async` / `await`.

It uses the `google.script.url.getLocation` client-side, to pull URL parameters and then send them off to other async functions.

There must be a way to do this elegantly.

```
var  doSomeAsyncShit =()=> {
    google.script.url.getLocation(function (location) {

      var rid = (location.parameter.rid) ? location.parameter.rid : defaultReportID;
      var uid = (location.parameter.uid) ? location.parameter.uid : defaultUserID;

      console.log (((location.parameter.rid) ? "Report #" : "Default Report ID #")+rid);
      console.log (((location.parameter.uid) ? "User #" : "Default User ID #" )+uid);

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(paintReport).returnJSON(rid);
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getMyReportsList).listMyReports(uid);
    });

  }

  

  $(function () {

    doSomeAsyncShit();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: You can't await that because it takes a callback vs returning a promise

Comment: @pguardiario Any function that takes a callback can be refactored to return a Promise using Promise constructors.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: you cannot await `google.script.url.getLocation` because it does not return a promise. You cannot refactor it either for obvious reasons. You *can* wrap it in a promise if that feels more elegant to you, but I would personally leave it as it is.

Comment: @pguardiario yeah, kind of? Isn't that what the OP wants, to refactor a function that uses `google.script.url` to work with promises, not the `getLocation` method itself (which they indeed could not do even if they wanted to)? True, it doesn't do much, but it helps maintainability and readability of the codebase by making it consistent. After all, that's one of the reasons Node.js started to move towards promise-based API.

Comment: @oleg I  guess I just disagree that it helps maintainability or readability. YMMV.

Comment: @pguardiario *You can wrap it in a promise*. Why do you think wrapping something in a promise and a default promise is different from each other?  Once wrapped, It returns a promise regardless of where it came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) can be constructed with a custom executor function, you can wrap the `google.script.url` into it and resolve or reject whenever you like. If you then make it a utility function, use `await` to wait for it to resolve.

Below is a small flexible utility for making `google.script.url` async-friendly:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  hash : string,
 *  parameter : Object.<string, string>,
 *  parameters : Object.<string, string[]>
 * }} UrlLocationObject
 * 
 * @typedef {{
 *  callback : function (UrlLocationObject, ...any) : any,
 *  params : any[]
 * }} AsyncUrlOptions
 * 
 * @summary Promise-friendly google.script.url
 * @param {AsyncUrlOptions}
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
const asyncLocation = ({
    callback,
    params = [],
}) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        google.script.url.getLocation((loc) => {
            try {
                const result = callback(loc, ...params);
                res(result);
            }
            catch(error) {
                rej(error);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Same goes for `google.script.run`:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  funcName : string,
 *  onFailure : function,
 *  onSuccess : function,
 *  params : array
 * }} AsyncOptions
 * 
 * @summary v2 of async-friendly google.script.run
 * @param {AsyncOptions}
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
const asyncGAPIv2 = ({
    funcName,
    onFailure = console.error,
    onSuccess,
    params = []
}) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(data => {
                typeof onSuccess === "function" && onSuccess(data);
                res(data);
            })
            .withFailureHandler(error => {
                typeof onFailure === "function" && onFailure(error);
                rej(error);
            })
        [funcName].apply(null, params);
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why is there a callback param if you're returning a promise?

Comment: @TheMaster I just thought that it might be useful in case one wants to invoke a handler before resolving/rejecting the promise for some side-effects. Other than that - a not particularly important part.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to intercept requests to google api and directly return [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) using [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

#### Script:

```
/**
 * Revives old client facing google api in apps script web applications
 * Directly returns promises for `google.scipt.run` and `google.script.url.getLocation`
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537867/
 */
(function projectAdrenaline_google() {
  const lifeline = {
    funcList: [],
    excludeList: [
      'withSuccessHandler',
      'withFailureHandler',
      'withUserObject',
      'withLogger',
    ],
    get: function(target, prop, rec) {
      if (this.excludeList.includes(prop))
        //return (...rest) => new Proxy(Reflect.apply(target[prop], target, rest), trap);
        throw new TypeError(
          `${prop}: This method is deprecated in this custom api`
        );
      if (this.funcList.includes(prop))
        return (...rest) =>
          new Promise((res, rej) =>
            target
              .withSuccessHandler(res)
              .withFailureHandler(rej)
              [prop](...rest)
          );
      switch (prop) {
        case 'run':
          this.funcList = Object.keys(target.run);
          break;
        case 'getLocation':
          return () => new Promise(res => target[prop](res));
      }
      return new Proxy(Reflect.get(target, prop, rec), lifeline);
    },
  };
  //const superGoogle = new Proxy(google, trap);
  //OR overwrite currently loaded google object:
  google = new Proxy(google, lifeline);
})();
```

#### Example:

```
const doSomeAsyncStuff = async () => {
  const location = await google.script.url.getLocation();

  const rid = location.parameter.rid ? location.parameter.rid : defaultReportID;
  const uid = location.parameter.uid ? location.parameter.uid : defaultUserID;

  //promise
  google.script.run.returnJSON(rid).then(paintReport);
  //async-await
  const reportsList = await google.script.run.listMyReports(uid);
  getMyReportsList(reportsList);
};
```

Alternatively, It is possible to use functions as syntactic sugars. But this requires learning new syntax definitions:

```js
/**
 * Syntactic sugar around old callback api returning a promise
 *
 * @returns {promise} Promise of call from server
 * @param {string[]|string} propertyAccesors Array of properties to access
 * @param {object[][]} methodAccesors Array of [method_to_access,arguments[]]
 * @param {number[]} resRejIdxs 2 Indexes of methodAccesors corresponding to resolve/success and rejection/failure. If omitted promise is resolved immediately.
 */
const GS = (propertyAccesors, methodAccesors, resRejIdxs) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    //Boilerplate for type correction
    const nestArray = e => (Array.isArray(e) ? e : [e]);
    propertyAccesors = nestArray(propertyAccesors);
    methodAccesors = nestArray(methodAccesors);
    methodAccesors[0] = nestArray(methodAccesors[0]);
    if (typeof resRejIdxs !== 'undefined') {
      resRejIdxs = Array.isArray(resRejIdxs) ? resRejIdxs : [resRejIdxs];
      resRejIdxs[0] && (methodAccesors[resRejIdxs[0]][1] = res);
      resRejIdxs[1] && (methodAccesors[resRejIdxs[1]][1] = rej);
    } else {
      res('Done');
    }

    //Access properties and call methods
    methodAccesors.reduce(
      (acc, [method, methodArg]) =>
        Array.isArray(methodArg)
          ? acc[method](...methodArg)
          : acc[method](methodArg),
      propertyAccesors.reduce(
        (acc, currentProp) => acc[currentProp],
        google.script
      )
    );
  });

//EXAMPLES:
GS(
  'run',
  [
    ['withSuccessHandler', null],
    ['callServer', [5, 4]], //call server function `callServer` with 2 arguments 5 and 4
    ['withFailureHandler', null],
  ],
  [0, 2] //0 is withSuccessHandler and 2 is withFailureHandler
).then(alert);

GS('history', [['setChangeHandler', e => console.log(e.location.hash)]]);
GS('url', 'getLocation', 0).then(location => console.log(location.hash));
GS(['host', 'editor'], 'focus');
GS('host', ['setHeight', 50]);
```

Comment: I think that this is a good idea. I could know that Proxy can be used for this situation, and could study from your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. Means a lot coming from you:)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this isn't too bad:

```
var doSomeAsyncShit = async () => {
  let location = await new promise(resolve => google.script.url.getLocation(resolve))
  // do stuff with location
}

(async () => {
  await doSomeAsyncShit();
  // do something after
})()
```

Even still, you've added complexity, reduced readability and for no good reasom IMHO

Comment: IMO, You're missing the big picture. The reason promises were introduced, amongst many other things, were avoidance of [callback hell/pyramid of doom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining). Promises, even if it were syntactic sugars over callbacks would greatly help in maintaining readability by avoiding such pyramids(OP currently has  atleast 2 layers: 2 `google.script.run` inside `google.script.url` callback)

Comment: In many cases promises are the way to go, but not this one. Again this is just IMHO.