# Modal dialog doesn't write back to sheet, when google.script.host.close() is used

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I have a very simple Google Apps Script which uses `showModalDialog()` to open an HTML form over a spreadsheet. The popup tries to send an input value back to the sheet and then close itself. The problem is *sometimes* the popup's POST request (called using `google.script.run()`) is cancelled and the sheet is not updated.

[image: error message]

When I remove the call to `google.script.host.close()` the request completes successfully and the sheet is updated. **EDIT:** Arrgh, I swear this used to work, but now I can't get the data written back to the sheet under any circumstances. Removing the `close()` does allow the callback to be sent successfully, though.

I've tried using async/await or a success handler (see bottom of question) but neither have worked. **How do I make the popup self-closing after the data is successfully sent?**

Here's the server-side code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Test Menu')
      .addItem('Open Test Popup', 'showPopup')
      .addToUi();
  return false;
}

function showPopup(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Popup').evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(350);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Test Title');
  return false;
}

function writeCustomValue(valueToWrite) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  cell.setValue(valueToWrite);
  return false;
}
```

Here's the popup client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>    
   
    <div class="block form-group">
      <label for="valueToWrite">Write this value</label>
      <input type="text" id="valueToWrite">
    </div>
    <button id="writeResponse" onclick='writeResponse()' class="action block">Write this value</button>
        
<script>
function writeResponse(){
   document.getElementById('writeResponse').innerHTML = 'Saving ...';
   document.getElementById('writeResponse').disabled = true;
   //Get the value of the input field 
   var valueToWrite = document.getElementById('valueToWrite').value;
   //Send the value of the text field as an argument to the server side function.
   google.script.run.writeCustomValue(valueToWrite);
   google.script.host.close();
}

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. Putting `host.close()` in a success handler:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).writeCustomValue(valueToWrite);
```

2. Async/await:

```
async function writeResponse(){
   document.getElementById('writeResponse').innerHTML = 'Saving ...';
   document.getElementById('writeResponse').disabled = true;
   //Get the value of the input field 
   var valueToWrite = document.getElementById('valueToWrite').value;
   //Send the value of the text field as an argument to the server side function.
   await google.script.run.writeCustomValue(valueToWrite);
   google.script.host.close();
}
```

Comment: For me your script works without issues. Try to close all instances of the spreadsheet and open again, refresh browser session, change browser, sing out of all accounts but one, use incognito.

Comment: Don't put parentheses on `withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close())`.  That is equivalent to `withSuccessHandler(undefined)` (the return value of the function). Pass just the function name: `withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)`

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka after clearing cache and logging out and back in, things started working as expected. It seems Google Apps Scripts don't properly handle multiple Google accounts being logged in at once.

Comment: @MartinBurch - oh yes, multiple accounts being logged in at once have been a bane of GAS for a long time, some issues are still not fixed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) takes a function as input, which means you need to pass in the name of the function **without parentheses**.  Adding the parentheses passes in the **return value of the function**, not the function definition.

You wrote

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).writeCustomValue(valueToWrite);
```

when you meant

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).writeCustomValue(valueToWrite);
```

Your code runs as expected in my Sheet after updating `writeResponse` accordingly.

As for the `async/await`, `google.script.run.writeCustomValue()` does not return a Promise (it's return type is `undefined`) and is therefore not something you can `await`.  Just adding that keyword does not change the definition of `google.script.run` or the objects therein.  When run, you `await` nothing and the script *immediately moves onto the next line just as if `await` were not there.

(* perhaps "immediately" is the wrong word: [the value of the expression (`undefined`) following `await` is converted into a resolved Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await); I leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out **exactly** when it will run, but I believe the effect in this situation is that it is run "immediately" in a loose sense.)

Comment: This works well, but is a little slow. I imagine it's because there are now two consecutive round-trips to the server. It's too bad the window can't close itself client side. However, many thanks!

Comment: Well, it will be run depending on how many macrotasks are left before the enqueued microtask will be run. Technically, if this is the only task left, for all intents and purposes it can be considered "immediate", just not "instant". Also, @MartinBurch - see this Q&A for examples on converting callback-based `google.script` APIs to promise-based APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63531403/11407695