# function won't run when executed from htmlService?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to switch my current sheet after 5s of the htmlService modalDialog opening.
For some reason `SwitchToSheet1()` does not work...

**.gs**

```
function openModal() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('BarcodeLoadingHTML')
  .evaluate()
  .setWidth(400)
  .setHeight(250);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "‎");
}

function SwitchToSheet1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Bestandsliste'), true);
};
```

**BarcodeLoadingHTML.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('jQuery'); ?>
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
    <?!= include('lottieplayer'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="loading">
        <lottie-player id="lottie-load" src="https://static.staticsave.com/lottie/cloudupload.json"  
          background="transparent"  
          speed="1" 
          loop 
          autoplay>
        </lottie-player>
        <lottie-player id="lottie-success" src="https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/private_files/lf30_qXYuJE.json"  
          background="transparent"  
          speed="1">
        </lottie-player>
        <p class="loadingtext" id="text">Bitte warten<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(window).ready(setTimeout (function() {
            $('#lottie-load').hide()
            $('#text').text('Upload Erfolgreich!')
            $('#lottie-success').fadeIn()
            $('#lottie-success').get(0).play();
        }, 2500));
        
        $(window).ready(setTimeout (function() {
            google.script.run.SwitchToSheet1();
            google.script.host.close();
        }, 5000));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove ``host.close()``

Comment: @TheMaster removing google.script.host.close(); does nothing besides the dialog not closing anymore

Comment: Logs? Any errors in execution logs?

Comment: Provide modal dialog code. Need [mcve] to reproduce. Provide the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: I'm guessing that `setActive()` won't work from that context.

Comment: Do you have a alternative idea?

Comment: @TheMaster no err in the execution logs but i got this in chrome: " There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit', name: 'TransportError', "

Comment: If the answer you marked was correct, shouldn't my first suggestion of removing `host.close()` worked? Did you guess or did you actually try my suggestion?

Comment: i did try it, nothing happened idk if there was a something else going wrong but rubens solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
google.script.run.SwitchToSheet1();
google.script.host.close();
```

by

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close())
.SwitchToSheet1();
```

The above because  `google.script.host.close()` is executing before `google.script.run.SwitchToSheet1()`. This happens because calls to server code using `google.script.run` are asynchronous, in other words, the Google servers not all the time responds instantly when they are called by `run`, so `google.script` retry until the server responds, but if the dialog is closed, there aren't more attempts to call the server.

Related

- [Auto close modal dialog - After server code is done, close dialog in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32527682/1595451)
- [Modal dialog doesn't write back to sheet, when google.script.host.close() is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63595698/1595451)

Answer (score -2):

FWIW, assuming I have a spreadsheet with two sheets named Sheet1 and Sheet2, and Sheet2 is the active, the following code works for me:

```
// Code.gs
function showDialog() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
   .setWidth(400)
   .setHeight(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog'); 
}

function SwitchToSheet1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sh, true);
};
```

And the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>            
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        setTimeout (function() {
            google.script.run.SwitchToSheet1();
            google.script.host.close();
        }, 5000)
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might not work all the time (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706218/1595451)).

Comment: @Rubén  I realize that google.script.run is async; I just don't know if it's a relevant issue here. I think that because .run comes before .host, it will always be invoked. It might be executed on the server after the modal closes but that shouldn't hinder its execution. Do you see it differently?

Comment: sometimes  `close` might run before `run` is called. When this happens the call to the server will not be done.

Comment: I think that  the server not all the time responds instantly when it's called by `run`, so google.script retry until the server responds, but if the dialog is closed, there aren't more attempts to call the server.

Comment: My understanding is that the server may not respond instantly, but I it will never  ignore a .run command. It will eventually execute it. Can you please point me to  documentation that shows how the client makes multiple .run calls until it gets a response?

Comment: While no one at Google had documented this, it is known by testing. If you're unable to reproduce this, try different browsers. `close()` is a client side close and is probably faster than the `run` request to server, which may stop midway(say `POST` fails midway).

Comment: @Ben I think that it might be possible "documented"  by someone (Google I/O speakers, IEEE paper authors, bloggers, etc.) but I can't give you a link at this time. I suggest you to spend some time learning about profiling web applications, more specifically about tools and methods to measure client-server communication performance.